# jQuery code is not speeding up with a variable

Tags: html, jquery, css

This code is programmed to make something that has a tab that changes text's color, but for some reason the speed won't change. Can anyone help? It has an area to change the way the text scrolls, but the speed won't work. I need to be able to change the speed to make sure the code works.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var easingisis = $("#text").val();
    var easingis = easingisis;
    var speedisis = $("#text2").val();
    var speedis = speedisis;
    $("p").slideUp(speedis, easingis, function() {
      $("h1").slideUp(speedis, easingis, function() {
        $("h1").toggleClass("red");
        $("p").toggleClass("red");
        $("h1").slideDown(speedis, easingis, function() {
          $("p").slideDown(speedis, easingis, function() {});
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: FreeMono, monospace;
  color: #000000;
}

.xmclass {
  text-align: center;
}

.xmbuttonclass {
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.red {
  color: #FF0000;
}

input {
  font-family: FreeMono, monospace;
}

button {
  font-family: FreeMono, monospace;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Adds jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="h1class" class="xmclass">NaN</h1>
  <p class="xmclass">NaN</p>
  <button class="xmbuttonclass">1</button><br>
  <label for="text" class="xmbuttonclass" style="width: 100%; height: auto; position: absolute; left: 0%">Type of movement:</label><br>
  <input placeholder="Linear, Swing" style="width: 30%; height: auto; position: absolute; left: 35%" type="text" id="text" name="text"></input><br>
  <label for="text2" class="xmbuttonclass" style="width: 100%; height: auto; position: absolute; left: 0%">Movement speed:</label><br>
  <input placeholder="1000 = 1 second" style="width: 30%; height: auto; position: absolute; left: 35%" type="text" id="text2" name="text2"></input><br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Why do you use two variables `speadisis` and `speadis`?

Comment: I just noticed that. I'll just use 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`slideUp()` determines which variation you're using by checking the argument types. It only treats the first argument as the duration if it's a number, but `$("#text2").val()` returns a string. Convert it to a number with `parseInt()`.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("button").click(function() {
    var easingis = $("#text").val();
    var speedis = parseInt($("#text2").val());
    $("p").slideUp(speedis, easingis, function() {
      $("h1").slideUp(speedis, easingis, function() {
        $("h1").toggleClass("red");
        $("p").toggleClass("red");
        $("h1").slideDown(speedis, easingis, function() {
          $("p").slideDown(speedis, easingis, function() {});
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  font-family: FreeMono, monospace;
  color: #000000;
}

.xmclass {
  text-align: center;
}

.xmbuttonclass {
  position: absolute;
  left: 45%;
  width: 10%;
  text-align: center;
}

.red {
  color: #FF0000;
}

input {
  font-family: FreeMono, monospace;
}

button {
  font-family: FreeMono, monospace;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <!-- Adds jQuery -->
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 id="h1class" class="xmclass">NaN</h1>
  <p class="xmclass">NaN</p>
  <button class="xmbuttonclass">1</button><br>
  <label for="text" class="xmbuttonclass" style="width: 100%; height: auto; position: absolute; left: 0%">Type of movement:</label><br>
  <input placeholder="Linear, Swing" style="width: 30%; height: auto; position: absolute; left: 35%" type="text" id="text" name="text"></input><br>
  <label for="text2" class="xmbuttonclass" style="width: 100%; height: auto; position: absolute; left: 0%">Movement speed:</label><br>
  <input placeholder="1000 = 1 second" style="width: 30%; height: auto; position: absolute; left: 35%" type="text" id="text2" name="text2"></input><br>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: It is now saying that there is an error in the script when I input speedis and easingis.

Comment: What error? Make sure the type of movement is a valid easing.

Comment: It turns out I have been using capitals at the start of easing. Thank you